# How to automate a website login in such a way that we should know each step whether its is executing or not in java...?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, headless

I need to automate the 3 click step first login and next page is the pay button, in code i am not getting any error but i am not able to verify that, whether it is executing every step or not, where it is failing, which click is missed out.

Here is my code please review it.

```
String URL = JsonPath.read(resp, "$..data.amazonPayResponse.amazonPayLoad.paymentRedirectUrl").toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]\"]", "").replaceAll("\\\\/", "/");
System.out.print("\n=============link==========\n"+URL);

WebDriver driver = new  HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get(URL);
driver.findElement(By.id("ap_email")).sendKeys("1234xxx123");
driver.findElement(By.id("ap_password")).sendKeys("xxxpasswordxxx");
driver.findElement(By.id("signInSubmit")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
WebElement payNowBtn = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span/span/input"))));
payNowBtn.click();
driver.quit();
```

Comment: i tried by xpath, by id, by class name, but still not able to do sucessfully, please help me here at least i should see where it is failing. which step is not clicked....

if any code i can write so that it shows that step is failed..

Comment: How did you derive that xpath expression?

Comment: Hi andersen i took by inspecting the web page and selecting the button event then copy the xpath.

Answer (score 0):

It is working when I use this path but still it only works in local machine not under Jenkins

```
By.xpath("//input[@name='ppw-widgetEvent:SetPaymentPlanSelectContinueEvent']")
```